# Level set of convex and plurisubharmonic functions (Ricci curvature and other curvature conditions)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $\phi$ be a stricly plurisubharmonic function on a domain in ${\Bbb C}^n$, and $S=\phi^{-1}(c)$ its level set. Consider $S$ as a Riemannian manifold equipped with a metric induced by $dd^c\phi$. I am interested in curvature restrictions on the Riemannian structure of $S$. In all examples I could check, its Ricci curvature is positive. Is it always true? What kind of restrictions we get?
Any ideas or reference would be appreciated.

I am thinking by analogy with a strictly convex function on a flat space: its Hessian is a metric, and its level set has (I think) positive curvature, though I don't have a formal proof of this either. I would appreciate a reference, or a refutation, if this is false.

Comment: It seems so, but I don't see an easy argument why the metric is induced by the Gauss map

Comment: Specifically, I want an argument which might be possibly generalized to the complex case

Comment: Moreover, it doesn't actually work in general:  For example, consider $f= 1/(z^2-x^2-y^2)$.  This is strictly convex on the domain (interior of a cone) where $x^2+y^2 < z^2$, but the function is invariant under the affine action of $\mathrm{SO}(2,1)$, so any induced metrics on the level sets of $f$ have to be invariant under this action as well, and that forces them to be hyperbolic metrics.

Comment: Do you have any smoothness condition on your PSH function? Otherwise what is a pull-back? What is curvature?

Comment: everything is smooth

Comment: @MishaVerbitsky:  I'm about to board a flight, so I don't have time to input a full answer, but I can say that the Ricci curvature of metric induced on the level sets of a strictly plurisubharmonic function is *not* always positive.  I think it is possible to characterize the induced metrics on level sets that you get this way intrinsically, but I haven't completely worked that out.  Maybe when I next get connected to the internet (tomorrow), I'll have that worked out.

Comment: many thanks! I would be very grateful, the question has some important geometric applications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I'm at the next airport and have a little time. While I don't have a complete answer worked out about the necessary and sufficient conditions on the curvature, I can definitely say that you don't get positivity of the Ricci curvature.

Here's an example:  In the domain $D\subset\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ defined by $|z_0|^2>|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+\cdots+|z_n|^2$, consider the nonnegative function
$$
\phi(z) = \frac{1}{|z_0|^2-|z_1|^2-|z_2|^2-\cdots - |z_n|^2}.
$$
Then it is easy to compute that $\phi$ is strictly plurisubharmonic in $D$ and that $\mathrm{d}\phi$ is nonvanishing in $D$.  The level sets of $\phi$, which are noncompact, are homogeneous under the action of the group $\mathrm{U}(1,n)$, so the Ricci curvature of the (necessarily complete) metric induced on each level set has constant eigenvalues. They cannot all be positive, for the level sets are not compact.  (In fact, it is not hard to see that all but at most one of the eigenvalues (the one tangent to the circle action) has to be negative.)

Obviously, this is the same sort of example as I gave for the case of the level sets of a strictly convex function on a domain in affine space, i.e., the function $f$ on the domain $D\subset\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ defined by ${x_0}^2> {x_1}^2 + \cdots + {x_n}^2$ defined by
$$
f(x) = \frac1{{x_0}^2- {x_1}^2 - \cdots - {x_n}^2},
$$
to show that the desired positivity doesn't work for Hessians either.

Comment: Nice answer, I was waiting for answer of this question :)